# CSS: Div display is set to block but they are showing inline

Tags: css

I seem to have a problem that is the opposite of what everyone else has. I want my div elements to display above each other like they normally do, since their default display is 'block', but they are not. My divs are placed inside a larger div element, and each of them contains only a single link.

Here is how they are showing:

[image]

I have forced the divs to 'display:block', and also the 'a' tags to 'display: block', but it has not solved the problem. Actually, when I inspect the element, the display is surprisingly set to 'block', yet my divs are still showing next to each other.

[image]

Here is the Html and CSS (note that I repeated some styles just to try to make it work):

```css
    .wrapper-div{
 padding: 20px;
 padding-top: 70px;
    }

    .wrapper-div a{
 float: left;
 padding: 4px;
 display: block;
    }

    .wrapper-div div{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
    }

    .link{
 display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
    <div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
    <div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
    </div>
```

This is extremely weird as I can't find a way to force the divs to become vertically aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.wrapper-div{
padding: 20px;
padding-top: 70px;
}

.wrapper-div a{
float: left;
padding: 4px;
...
display: block;
}

.wrapper-div div{
display: block;
width: 100%;
clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
<div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
<div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
<div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
</div>
```

Just Add clear:both;   where I indicated

Comment: Okay, a very big thank you to you. The 'clear: both' solved the problem.

Comment: the float was causing it, clear:both takes care of it

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overthinking this.

Example

```css
.wrapper-div {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-top: 70px
}
    
.link{
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
    <div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
    <div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
    <div class="link"> <a href="#">Bla1</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: He definatly is overthinking it, but if he wants to keep his same html and css, my response is below with a fix.